# Can't set properties on nested classes from Xaml

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The error that Xamarin gives back: Type Foo not found in xmlns clr-namespace:AmsterdamTheMapV3

The problem is that I am trying to define Foo but whatever I do it doenst work. I think that the problem is inside the xmls:local namespace. Maybe I make a stupid mistake inside my code.

This is a Xamarin.forms project for windows, android and apple.

Xaml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AmsterdamTheMapV3.CityGuide"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AmsterdamTheMapV3">
  <Label Text="{Binding MainText}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
  <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  Spacing="0">

      <!-- Button1 -->
      <Image
          x:Name="CityGuideButton1"
          Source="shopping_gray.png"
          Aspect="Fill"
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions ="FillAndExpand"
          local:Foo.Tag="button1">
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
          <TapGestureRecognizer
            Tapped="Categorie_Onclick"
            NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
      </Image>
    </StackLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace AmsterdamTheMapV3
{
    public partial class CityGuide : ContentPage
    {
        public CityGuide()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

         public class Foo
        {
            public static readonly BindableProperty TagProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Tag", typeof(string), typeof(Foo), null);

            public static string GetTag(BindableObject bindable)
            {
                return (string)bindable.GetValue(TagProperty);
            }

            public static void SetTag(BindableObject bindable, string value)
            {
                bindable.SetValue(TagProperty, value);
            }
        }


        async void Categorie_Onclick(Object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Image cmd = sender as Image;
            string txt = Foo.GetTag(cmd);
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new CategoriePage(txt));
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that somewann can help me.
I can give more info if needed.
thank you in advance!

Comment: Please note that your Xaml probably doesn't display what you expect. Your contentPage has 2 children, a `Label` and a `ScrollView`, but `ContentPage` only accept a single property as `Content`. At the time of the writing, the Xamarin.Forms Xaml parser is quite forgiving, and one of the 2 items is ignored (usually all but the last one), but that could change, and throw, in the future.

Comment: I did change it after the upload of this Question. The label was not supposed to be there. But still thank you for the feedback. And i will keep this one in mind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You can't reference nested classes from `Xaml`.**

You can quote me on this, or google it, but this is an universal truth. The reason is that Xaml Parsers would not be able to differentiate an Attached (Bindable|Dependency)Property from a nested class access, based on the dot sign.

In your case, move your Foo class from within CityGuide directly to the namespace and it should work.

Your xmlns declaration `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AmsterdamTheMapV3"` is correct without the `assembly=` part as you are referring to the current assembly.

More info on a similar answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/14546917/1063783

Some might ask why not use the `+` sign for nested class (like it's done in Reflection). The problem is that an a name containing a `+` sign is not a valid xml-element name (https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/07/25/namingparts.html)

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the assembly reference.

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AmsterdamTheMapV3; assembly=AmsterdamTheMapV3">
```

From Xamarin:

> To access classes local to the shared application PCL, such as AppConstants, XAML programmers often use the prefix local. The namespace declaration must indicate the CLR (Common Language Runtime) namespace name (also known as the .NET namespace name, which is the name that appears in a C# namespace definition or in a using directive) and the assembly containing the code.

Comment: @N.Smeding Check the assembly name in your Project File, they should match. I assumed it was *AmsterdamTheMapV3* however, go to your ProjectFile.csproj, find assembly name, and replace that in assembly=

Comment: where can i find the asssembly name can't find it inside the propeties.

Comment: The assembly name is the same

RootNamespace: AmsterdamTheMapV3
AssemblyName: AmsterdamTheMapV3