# How to change a custom type to System type (string) in WPF XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use nested class in WPF XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546347/how-to-use-nested-class-in-wpf-xaml)

I am refractoring the code from sample:

- [24.129.21. Master Detail Binding](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0470__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/MasterDetailBinding.htm)
  from [C# / CSharp Tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/CatalogCSharp.htm) » Windows Presentation Foundation » Binding)

And [after excluding Skills class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14536818/200449), with corresponding changes in
in **MainWindow.xaml**

```
<local:Team>
  <local:Employee Name="Larry" Age="21">
    <local:Employee.Skills>
      <!--  local:Skills -->
       <local:Skills>
```

I am having in **MainWindow1.xaml.cs**:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
namespace WpfApplication
{
  public class Skill
  {//I'd like to remove class Skill having moved property string Description into class Employee 
    public string Description { get; set; }
  }

   public class Employee 
   {
    public string Name { get  ; set; }
    public int Age  { get; set; }
//I'd like to change in the next line Skill --> String               
    public List<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
    //public List<String> Skills { get; set; }

     public Employee()
     {
//I'd like to change in the next line Skill --> String       
       Skills=new List<Skill>();
       //Skills=new List<string>();
     }
  }

  public class Team : ObservableCollection<Employee> { }

  public class Company
  {
    public string CompanyName { get  ; set; }
    public Team Members { get  ; set; }
  }

  public class Companies : ObservableCollection<Company> { }

  public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
      public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
}
```

How should I change Window1.XAML if to change:

- `List<Skill>` to `List<String>`

in Window1.xaml.cs?

Related questions based on the same code:

- [How to use nested class in WPF XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546347/how-to-use-nested-class-in-wpf-xaml)
- [Is it possible to use anonymous types in WPF XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539860/is-it-possible-to-use-anonymous-types-in-wpf-xaml)

Update:
Just to note what I tried wrong:

- "A" instead of A (without quotes);
- it should be `String` (but not `string`) in XAML (while in C# either `string` or `String`)
- tried to place A as attribute, according existed code, in one tag `<sys:String />` 
    instead of:  `<sys:String>A</sys:String>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here goes your Employee class with new approach you wanted it to be like -

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<String> Skills { get; set; }

    public Employee()
    {
        Skills=new List<string>();
    }
}
```

You can create the instance in xaml files for the same like this -

```
        <local:Team x:Key="teams">
            <local:Employee Name="Larry" Age="21">
                <local:Employee.Skills>
                    <sys:String>A</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>B</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>C</sys:String>
                </local:Employee.Skills>
            </local:Employee>
        </local:Team>
```

You need to define `sys` namespace in your xaml to declare an instance of string in xaml -

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

I tested the above code with `ListBox` and its working -

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Skills, Source={StaticResource teams}}"/>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. The problem was that I've never written XML manually before - only editor- or Intellisense assisted. And WPF editor is not very friendly in that

Comment: Could you possibly enclose all XAML script? While it became clear how to use String type in XAML, I was in a hurry to accept your answer without succeeding to running it in context of master-detail